# Workstation "joining" a domain

Tags: exchange, active-directory

I have a question about domain joining workstations. We just upgraded Exchange and AD to a new server. I want to know how I join these old workstations to the new domain controller and preserve all the users documents etc.

In other words I don't want to create another user account on the workstations.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Are you saying that the old AD server is already dead or you are wanting advice to migrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the new server a member of the old domain?  If they are part of the same domain, then you don't have to do anything.

I

Comment: We are putting the old server to rest.

Comment: Yes, but you still haven't answered the critical question.  Is your new server a DC in the same domain as the old server, or did you create a completely new forest/domain?

Comment: We created completly new forest/domain

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating another user *account* but your creating another user **profile**.

1. Create two way trust relation between the two domains.
2. Install [ADMT](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=AE279D01-7DCA-413C-A9D2-B42DFB746059&displaylang=en).
3. Read ADMT migration [guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=B1F816C0-4E2B-4E5D-B256-1AC304062367&displaylang=en). If you move the user and computer accounts from the source domain it should keep the sids so you won't need to re-configure the user profile. Exchange is whole nother story.

Comment: We are putting the old server to rest.

Comment: Ok, have you looked at my suggestion. This should be able to help you do what you are asking.